# What is the meaning of the phrase ‘to offer to’?

Tags: word-meaning

I see this sentence in my book: It is very kind of you to offer to collect me from the station.

I can not understand the meaning of the phrase ‘to offer’.

Answer (score 1):

I could ask somebody the following question:

> "May I collect you from the station?"

This is an offer on my part. I am volunteering my aid, offering to help them make their way from the station to wherever they need to go.

My offer can be accepted or refused:

> "Yes, thank you. I would appreciate that."
>   "No, thank you. I already have transportation arranged."

In the sentence in question, the person is being told that they were kind to have asked about providing a ride from the station.

---

From Merriam-Webster's definition of [*offer*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/offer):

> **2 a** : to present for acceptance or rejection : TENDER
>   // was *offered* a job
>    **3 a** : PROPOSE, SUGGEST
>   // *offer* a solution to a problem
>   **3 b** : to declare one's readiness or willingness
>   // *offered* to help me

Comment: In my sentence, if the ‘to offer’ were deleted, it can still express the meaning it now has. So, why added ‘to offer’ there?

Comment: @Y.zeng Offering to do something is not the same thing as *actually* doing something. If you delete *to offer*, then you are describing something different